# How to create directory outside project root directory with node.js?

Tags: node.js, linux, fs, directory-structure, mkdir

Iam new here..
I am trying to create a directory outside of root project directory where i will read and write from a file created by library automatically.
Like i need to create a directory in "/home/user/Documents/newdirectory"
Iam working with linux.

I tried with below code with node.js ,but it is creating a directory at the project folders itself.
Can anyone plz suggest on this?

```
fs.mkdir("./files/a/new-directory-name", { recursive: true }, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log("New directory successfully created.")
  }
})



>It is created a directory but in root project directory. 
But I need to create a dirwctory at $Home/user/Documents/newdirectory.
```

Answer (score 1):

A path that begins with `.` is a relative path. Node fs uses `process.cwd()` as the root for relative paths.

If you need to create a directory at `/home/user/Documents/newdirectory`, then that's exactly what you should pass in to fs.mkdir():

```js
fs.mkdir("/home/user/Documents/newdirectory", ...
```

Comment: Errno:-2, code:ENOENT, syscall:mkdir errors showed, didnot create any directory at this path.

Comment: Can anybody support on this ? I have to create a directory in $HOME/$USER/Documents in linux and then read and write this directory?